# What are the default BLE(bluetooth) services for phone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have been exploring & reading a lot about BLE for iOS.It says we have to access the services & characteristics  for reading or writing some data to a peripheral but i have a doubt how we do it with two mobile devices when we connect to a phone it does not show any services what we do

1-Turn on the bluetooth 
2-Select files to share 
3-Share files to connected device

What type of services are accessed in that process ?

Comment: There are no accessible file transfer services available to applications in an iOS device.  If you want to transfer files you need to have an app running on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to refer to this link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741 ?

Source code is available here: https://github.com/orepereira/CoreBluetooth